# Have a variable select from an array

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am trying to use a variable to select from an array:

This works:

```
var myarray = {bricks:3000, studs:500, shingles:400, tiles:700};

function One() {
   alert(myarray.bricks);
}
```

But this does not work:

```
var myarray = {bricks:3000, studs:500, shingles:400, tiles:700};

var myvalue = "bricks"

function Two() {
   alert(myarray.myvalue);
}
```

How do I do this properly? Here is a fiddle to show what I am trying to accomplish: https://jsfiddle.net/chrislascelles/xhmx7hgc/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[]` notation.

```
var myarray = {bricks:3000, studs:500, shingles:400, tiles:700};

function One() {
       alert(myarray.bricks);
}


var myvalue = "bricks"  //supplied here to make example work

function Two() {
       alert(myarray[myvalue]);
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xhmx7hgc/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The variable is not an array, it's an object.

To access an element from object using variables you should use Bracket Notation like bellow

```
alert(myarray[myvalue]);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xhmx7hgc/5/)

Comment: What's next? Answering a question about using `+` to add numbers, and providing a fiddle to show how that works?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you are lacking is the syntax. Here is how it works:

```
function Two() {
   alert(myarray[myvalue]);
}
```

In javascript, it means the same thing to write these two:

```
var a = {};
a.foo = "hello";
a["bar"] = "world";

a.bar; // world;
a["foo"]; // hello;
```